# deletion in linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

This is my deletion code. The problem is that when i delete something from the tail or an nth node it works perfectly fine but whenever i delete something from the **head** it crashes. What check should i make in order to avoid the crash?

```
void List::Delete(int data) {
// Create a temp pointer
Node *tmp = head;

// No nodes
if ( tmp == NULL )
return;

// Last node of the list
if ( tmp->Next() == NULL ) {
delete tmp;
head = NULL;
}
else {
// Parse through the nodes
Node *prev;
do {
    if ( tmp->Data() == data ) break;
    prev = tmp;
    tmp = tmp->Next();
} while ( tmp != NULL );

// Adjust the pointers
prev->SetNext(tmp->Next());

// Delete the current node
delete tmp;
}
```

}

Comment: What does "it crashes" mean exactly? At what line? How can anyone given the code reproduce the problem?

Comment: `while ( tmp != NULL );` ensures that when you cross this point `tmp` will definitely be `NULL` therefore `prev->SetNext(tmp->Next());` will produce a segmentation fault.

Comment: `if ( tmp->Next() == NULL ) {
delete tmp;
head = NULL;
}` here you do not even ensure that `tmp->Data() == data` and delete the node.

Answer (score 1):

If the node to delete is the head node, then this is what happens:

You declare `Node *prev`. Notice that it is uninitialised. Then you enter the `do while` loop, but break at the first if condition because `tmp->Data() == data`. So you exit the do while loop without executing the next statement, which would initialise `prev`. Now out of the loop, the next statement accesses the `SetNext` field of `prev`, whereas previous is unitialised. This is undefined behavior, and anything can happen; crashing is one such thing.

The way to avoid this is to add a check for whether `prev` is unitialised, or 'tmp' is the head node. In this case, you should delete the head, and return the node after head. Since your function has a `void` signature, you should delete the head node, and make the head pointer reference the node after head.

Comment: You beat me to the answer. Note: The behavior of the program is undefined (i.e., it is not guaranteed to crash).

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one problems with this code.

- `if ( tmp->Next() == NULL )` this check does not mean "Last node of the list" infact it means that **there is only one node in the list** since the code below only runs if there are at least two nodes you need to handle this case here.
- `tmp->Data() == data` check is needed in addition to the above check to make sure that the only node in the list is also the node we want to delete before deleting it.
- `Node *prev = NULL;` this pointer should be initialized so that we can check for `NULL` later to see if it is the head that needs to be deleted.
- Also all the deletion should be done inside the loop checking for `if ( tmp->Data() == data )` before the `break;` is applied, otherwise you will have no way to know if the loop ended naturally or was broken, to decide whether the node was found or not.

Here is the corrected code:

```
void List::Delete(int data) {
 // Create a temp pointer
 Node *tmp = head;

 // No nodes
 if ( tmp == NULL )
 return;

 // it is the only node in the list
 if ( tmp->Next() == NULL && tmp->Data() == data ) {
  delete tmp;
  head = NULL;
 }
 else {
  // Parse through the nodes
  Node *prev = NULL;
  do {
      if ( tmp->Data() == data ){
       if( prev == NULL ) // this is the head case
        head = head->Next();
       else // Adjust the pointers
        prev->SetNext(tmp->Next());
       // Delete the current node
       delete tmp;
       break;
      }
      prev = tmp;
      tmp = tmp->Next();
  } while ( tmp != NULL );
 }
}
```

**Note:** The tail case works fine without any alterations in the code because, the only difference that this case creates, is that `tmp->Next()` for that case would be `NULL` which is exactly what we want for the new tail in `prev->SetNext(tmp->Next());` i.e. set its `Next` to `NULL`.